# How to get a QModelIndex of a row, found by a SELECT-query (QSqlQuery) without modifying the original QSqlQueryModel

Tags: qt, qt4, qtsql, qmodelindex

I already asked the question but I was misunderstood, so I try to precicise the problem.

I am using a `QSqlQueryModel` for showing data from a SQLite Database, for the view I use a `QTableView`.

Now I want to implement a "Search/Find/Replace" dialog, so I search the database with an additionally created `QSqlQuery` and let's say I find the record.

So how do I come from this found record in my extra `QSqlQuery` to my model/view-architecture?

The problem is, I want to highlight the found record and therefore I have to load a `QItemSelectionModel` with a specific `QModelIndex`.

But I do not know any way how to do this, maybe my plan is not possible and there are other working solutions for finding text in a database model and highlighting the found ones in the `QTableView`.

I already know the documentation of `QSqlQuery`, `QSqlQueryModel` and `QModelIndex`, so please don't refer only to these pages, this wouldn't be much help..

Thanks!

PS: There is also a related question, which has not been answered yet: "How can i find the QModelIndex for given composite primary key, with QSqlTableModel"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found the answer myself, maybe somebody else has the same problem, so I post the solution:

There is a function QAbstractItemModel::match() :)